# Network plots in Shiny/visNetwork: inconsistent behaviour with dynamic group allocation

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, vis.js

I want to create an app where the colours of nodes change dynamically based on which node is selected (the idea is to show the output of a contagion model, where the highlighted nodes are the ones that would experience contagious defaults from the selected node - so it's not always just all the directly connected nodes that should be highlighted). In principle this should be possible by updating the group properties of the nodes with `visUpdateNodes`, however, it seems to behave very strangely:

If I simply udpate the group properties of the nodes, then the app will "remember" the previously colored nodes - i.e. every node that was coloured once will remain coloured, even if it shouldn't be under the currently selected node. I honestly have no idea why that's the case, I tried every debugging trick that I know but couldn't get an answer. I managed to create a workaround with a second observer-function that resets all the group properties. This works if I run the app on my local Windows machine from RStudio, but strangely, it does not work when I run it on my (Linux-based) server. There, the app simply does not colour the nodes at all (even though you sometimes see a quick spark of colours, which indicates that the code was executed, but then the second oberserver function was called again and cleared the properties). The example below demonstrates the problem:

global.R:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
group <- rep("",5)
nodes <- data.frame(id,group)

from <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
to <- c(2,3,4,1,3,5,5)
edges <- data.frame(from,to)

def1 <- c("","Default","Default","","")
def2 <- c("","","Default","Default","")
def3 <- c("","","","Default","")
def4 <- c("","","","","Default")
def5 <- c("","","","","")

defs <- data.frame(def1,def2,def3,def4,def5)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$netplot <- renderVisNetwork({
    visNetwork(nodes,edges)%>% 
      visGroups(
        groupname = "Default", color = list(
          background = "red"
        )
      ) %>%
      visOptions(
        nodesIdSelection = list(
          enabled = TRUE
        )
      )
  })
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$netplot_selected)) {
      nodes$group <- rep("A",5)
      visNetworkProxy("netplot") %>% visUpdateNodes(nodes)      
    }
  })
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$netplot_selected)) {
      if(input$netplot_selected!="") {
        newgroup <- defs[,as.numeric(input$netplot_selected)]      
        nodes$group <- newgroup
      }
    }   
    visNetworkProxy("netplot") %>% visUpdateNodes(nodes)   
  })
})
```

ui.R:

```
library(visNetwork)
shinyUI(fluidPage(mainPanel(visNetworkOutput("netplot"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the package just pointed me to a solution on github - it turns out that `group = ""` is prone to such issues. Replacing the empty string with any string (and removing the first of the two observer functions) does the trick in the above example.